# How to only slide subpart of page with mmenu?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

When using the jQuery.mmenu-plugin, found here http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/, the whole page (body) slides when triggered. How can I make it to only slide part of my page instead? I would like a static header above and footer below which are not affected by the sliding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css :

You should set the header and footer to fixed position.

exemple :

```
<div id='header'> my header </div>
```

css :

```
#header{
  top:0px;
  position:fixed;
}
```